# Blender and MBdyn

Tags: python, animation

I was looking for aerodynamic simulation possibilities in blender and after some research landed to this page:

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?139557-Multibody-Dynamic-Simulation-Available-Now.

It took me about an hour to figure out that it won't work for 2.6x so I downloaded 2.49 portable, followed all the steps and got ready to run the script. When running the script, it would show missing module (`tempfile`, `numpy`, `scipy`) errors. Finally the last (I hope) error I got was that I cannot run `scipy` from the `numpy` source directory.

I've got no hint why is it caused.

Has anyone got a solution for the directory error, possibly for running MBDyn?

Comment: When writing questions on this site, please take the time and effort to at least put spaces after commas and full stops.

Comment: BlenderAndMBDyn v2 for Blender 2.72+ is now available at https://github.com/gdbaldw/BlenderAndMBDyn